# Swig not found when installing pocketsphinx Python

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, swig, pocketsphinx

I would like to convert grapheme to phoneme. And I want to pip install pocketsphinx to do that. One of its dependency is swig, so I downloaded and placed it in a directory and go to the environment path variable and add the path that leads to swig.exe. When I cmd and type 'swig --help' it seems to be working.

But when I go 'pip install pocketsphinx, it says 'error: command 'swig.exe failed: No such file or directory'.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pipwin to install it without any issues.

- Install pipwin [Run as Administrator, if any issues]

> pip install pipwin

- Install pocketsphinx using pipwin

> pipwin install pocketsphinx

Note: Works on Windows-10(win32-py3.8) [Tested]

Answer (score 3):

You should [setup swig in Visual Studio](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Windows.html#Windows_examples) instead of including its path in %PATH%.

Comment: how abstruse :(

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows is not every developer-friendly, so even if I or someone else had posted a step-by-step solution here, it would have quickly become outdated as SWIG is in rapid development. This may change though as we see Windows adopt Linux culture more and more.

Comment: Hopefully. Because for this project I'm stuck with this Windows environment sadly.

Comment: @JeromeJ What's your problem? Did you follow the link I provided?

Comment: That was probably on my end. This linked helped me fixing my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36785608/1524913 (now i have another one but it isn't Swig)