# Error installing PyMVPA2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm getting the following error when I try to install using pip install for PyMVPA2 for Python. I have installed other libraries without any problems before. I would appreciate if anything could take a look at the errors:

```
C:\Users\usr>pip install pymvpa2
Collecting pymvpa2
Using cached pymvpa2-2.4.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
running build_src
build_src
building extension "mvpa2.clfs.libsmlrc.smlrc" sources
building extension "mvpa2.clfs.libsvmc._svmc" sources
creating build
creating build\src.win32-2.7
creating build\src.win32-2.7\mvpa2
creating build\src.win32-2.7\mvpa2\clfs
creating build\src.win32-2.7\mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc
swig.exe++: mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc\svmc.i
swig.exe -python -I3rd\libsvm -c++ -I3rd\libsvm -o build\src.win32- 2.7\mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc\svmc_wrap.cpp -outdir build\src.win32-2.7\mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc\svmc.i
error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-v_zzkd\pymvpa2\
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states you either don't have swig installed or it is not on your path. You are obviously on Windows so you need to download the swig executable from [the swig website](http://www.swig.org/) - download the latest **windows** package and either unzip it to a directory on your existing path or to a new directory and add it to your path. Easiest, of course, is to unzip it to a new directory and then run your pip command in that directory.

- **What is swig anyway?** Swig parses the interface definitions of code written in C/C++ and can output 'glue code' to allow code written in Python & *a pile, currently 22, of other programming or scripting languages* to use the C/C++ code transparently. Swig is free, open source and compatible with both open source and commercial use.
- **Should I keep it to hand?** In most cases that I know of in python swig is only invoked during the installation or setup phase but since that setup phase will be used every time that **any** package built with swig is installed or ***upgraded*** there is no reason to get rid of it and quite a lot of reasons to have it somewhere on your path.

Comment: I have little clue as what Swig does, just that I required it to install my package. Is it safe to delete the Swig directory afterwards?

Comment: @JeromeJ - Added some info that should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove swig
sudo apt-get install swig3.0
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/swig3.0 /usr/bin/swig
```

and then

```
pip install pymvpa2
```