# Python can't install Box2D swig.exe failed with error code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, swig

I try to install Box2D on python but I get the error log:

```
C:\>pip3 install Box2D
Collecting Box2D
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/7b/ddb96fea1fa5b24f8929714ef483f64c33e9649e7aae066e5f5023ea426a/Box2D-2.3.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: Box2D
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Box2D ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\hp-laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\HP-LAP~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r48_7g5v\\Box2D\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\HP-LAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-d2ghuwrx --python-tag cp36:
  Using setuptools (version 40.5.0).
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D
  copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D
  copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D\b2
  copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D\b2
  running build_ext
  building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
  swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
  C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
  C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\pyprimtypes.swg(7) : Error: Syntax error in input(1).
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\HP-Laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\swig.exe' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for Box2D
  Running setup.py clean for Box2D
Failed to build Box2D
Installing collected packages: Box2D
  Running setup.py install for Box2D ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\hp-laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\HP-LAP~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r48_7g5v\\Box2D\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\HP-LAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nv5dm4ru\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Using setuptools (version 40.5.0).
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D\b2
    copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D\b2
    running build_ext
    building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
    swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
    C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
    C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\pyprimtypes.swg(7) : Error: Syntax error in input(1).
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\HP-Laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\swig.exe' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\hp-laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\HP-LAP~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r48_7g5v\\Box2D\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\HP-LAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nv5dm4ru\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HP-LAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r48_7g5v\Box2D\
```

I tried all solutions for windows from [Installing pocketsphinx python module: command 'swig.exe' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504899/installing-pocketsphinx-python-module-command-swig-exe-failed) without result.

How can I install Box2D and what means error code 1 by swig ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I got the same error for Box2D, but solved as follows.

I am using Anaconda environment with python3.6.

try these.

> conda install swig
>
> pip install box2d

Comment: There is now a PyPI package for SWIG, so `pip install swig` will work.

Answer (score 4):

download swig here : http://www.swig.org/download.html

Extract the archive somewhere, add the path of the extracted directory to your PATH environment variable.

Restart your cmd console window (close it and reopen it), do your `pip install Box2D`

I need to say  that  when on the  anaconda environment, just add path, it also doesn't work. we need to go on the Scripts with pip.exe. And run the command!

Answer (score 2):

I got same error for Box2D.
My Solution- 
downloading Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
Complete the installation.
Then on anaconda prompt
type command 'pip install Box2D'
Then type 'pip install gym[all]'
This will install the remaining dependencies.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever is on Windows and facing this issue. Try installing C++ tools on windows through https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/.
Then Install C++ tools through visual studio. This should solve your problem

Try Install Box2D after this (make sure Swig is installed)

Answer (score 1):

Hello there I must be late but I hope this helps someone to solve his problem.

Just use any package manager like `choco` or `conda` or any other package manager to install the `swig` package to your machine then run the command to install box2d again.

> choco install swig
>
> pip install box2d-py

Comment: There is now a PyPI package for SWIG, so `pip install swig` can be used instead of conda.