# i cant install any libraries

Tags: python, pip, installation, libraries

you are can see in this image my pip is updated
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, downloaded swig for windows

Copy swig.exe to the python installation folder (for ex C:/python27)

Open swigwin-3.0.12/Lib folder and copy all *.swg files to the C:/python27/lib or equivalent python path

Open swigwin-3.0.12/lib/python and copy all the files to (C:/python27/lib)

(Also make sure you have Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python installed)

These steps worked for me.
I was able to find a fix from another user

Comment: This is not work for me.How can I send you a certificate?

Comment: This is the only different answer I found. If this does not work, you will have to look into other forums
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504899/installing-pocketsphinx-python-module-command-swig-exe-failed/44507235#44507235