# pocketsphinx ERROR: Could not build wheels for pocketsphinx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, pocketsphinx

I am having trouble downloading this python module called pocketsphinx,
I've tried everything by downloading it manually, using git and more (I am on windows), I updated pip, and I even tried downloading visual studio with the python environment as the error insisted, i updated my python, I even tried updating my laptop, but I still can't get it to work. but I'm not giving up, although I am very frustrated.

`
FULL ERROR:
-- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator - failure
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.11 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  Or with "Visual Studio 2019":

      https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  Or with "Visual Studio 2022":

      https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  ********************************************************************************
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
Failed to build pocketsphinx
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pocketsphinx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
`

Updating my python, updating PIP, Updating my laptop, Installing it manually, and using GIT, ive even tried some solutions on youtube (none of them worked)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i just found the problem. turns out python 3.11 is completely unsupported. meaning you will have to downgrade to 3.10 to use this module

Answer (score 0):

By following the instruction here: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/
cd pocketsphinx-python
python setup.py install
```

You will most probably end up having this problem if you dont have swig: [Installing pocketsphinx python module: command 'swig.exe' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504899/installing-pocketsphinx-python-module-command-swig-exe-failed)

I didn't try it but it is indicated as resolved which indicates that it would probably solve your problem also